# Error when trying to run adonis JS migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Error is displayed when trying to run the migration.

I'm using the migration created by Adonis Auth himself. In which the token table is created.

The error is shown when trying to create this table and mariadb immediately closes.

I'm using mysql2

```
import BaseSchema from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Schema'

export default class ApiTokens extends BaseSchema {
  protected tableName = 'api_tokens'

  public async up() {
    this.schema.createTable(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.increments('id').primary()
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.string('name').notNullable()
      table.string('type').notNullable()
      table.string('token', 64).notNullable().unique()

      /**
       * Uses timestampz for PostgreSQL and DATETIME2 for MSSQL
       */
      table.timestamp('expires_at', { useTz: true }).nullable()
      table.timestamp('created_at', { useTz: true }).notNullable()
    })
  }

  public async down() {
    this.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
  }
}
```

Erro

```
node ace migration:run
[ info ]  Upgrading migrations version from "1" to "2"
❯ migrated database/migrations/1663627357202_users
❯ error database/migrations/1663627357216_api_tokens

  Error

 Connection lost: The server closed the connection.


   1  Socket.<anonymous>
     ..../node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend restarting the server `node ace serve --watch`, before running the migrations.